# How to define func to a specific case of Enum in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

```
enum Type {
    case A
    case B

    func do() {

    }
}
```

I would like do for available for case A

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. It is not possible to define functions specific to a case inside an Enum type.

Comment: I think he wants to define a function that can only be called by Type.A but not Type.B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible with enums.

However, it can be done with tricks.

First, create a class called `Type`:

```
class Type { private init() {} }
```

And create two classes, `AType` and `BType` to inherit `Type`:

```
// Put this in the same file as Type
class AType: Type { private init() {} }
class BType: Type { private init() {} }
```

The private initializer is to prevent external code to create `AType` and `BType` objects.

In `Type`, add these static properties:

```
static let A = AType()
static let B = BType()
```

Then you're basically done!

To add a method that only `Type.A` is accessible, just add it in the `AType` class!

This way, just like an enum, `Type.A` and `Type.B` can still be assigned to a `Type` object!

Comment: But it lost the accent of Enum in using `switch`. Anyway, thanks for the hack.

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking that checkmark. @user2215977